# Store multiple textareas in different array's index

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple `textarea` for example:

```
<textarea>test1</textarea>
<textarea>test2</textarea>
<textarea>test3</textarea>
```

I know how to iterate over all the textareas and get the values:

```
$(function(){
    $("textarea").each(function(){
      alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

**But how to store each textarea at a different index?**

This doesn't work:

```
var myArray=[];     
$(function(){
 $("textarea").each(function(){
  myArray.push(this.value);
 });
});
```

Doesn't matter if it's with JS or Jquery

Comment: The last one should result in ``["test1", "test2", "test3"]``. What are you expecting?

Comment: If you test the array after `$(function() {})` it will be empty you need to check after `each()` if you do check after each then you probably have completely different code, or you do something that you don't tell, because this looks correct.

Comment: Looks okay to me, but I removed the `$` wrapping the outer function, and made it self-executing: https://jsfiddle.net/d0bo16s3/1/

Comment: @Bucket `$(function() {})` is required if <textarea is after script tag, this is jQuery ready shortcut.

Comment: @Bucket removing the document ready changes the behavior.  The upvoted answer below explains why the logging of the array may be empty.

Comment: The problem is that the array will be filled after the document loads so you need to log it after that but you are logging it before so you get an empty array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are trying to log the array before the loop is executed:

```js
var myArray=[];     
$(function(){
  $("textarea").each(function(){
    myArray.push(this.value);
  });
  console.log('----after the loop execution-----');
  console.log(myArray); //["test1", "test2", "test3"]
});
console.log('----before the loop execution-----');
console.log(myArray); //[]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>test1</textarea>
<textarea>test2</textarea>
<textarea>test3</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    let answer = []
    let texts = document.querySelectorAll('textarea')
    texts.forEach( x => answer.push(x.value))
    console.log(answer)
```

```html
<textarea>test1</textarea>
<textarea>test22</textarea>
<textarea>test333</textarea>
```

Native code, you can make it without 'this'

Comment: This doesn't explain the original issue.

Comment: This don't answer the question which probably is caused by async jQuery ready or something that is not in the question.

Comment: @jcubic Why it's wrong? Maybe TS just don't know how to do this without jQuery. He ask  "But how to store each textarea at a different index?". My code do this. Autor agree with that and vote to my post, so why you don't agree with me?

Comment: The problem is most likely because of async request, he try to check the array before it's iterated over the textareas, you need to use same code as OP your code is completely different because in snippet you don't need to have jQuery Dom Ready, because textarea is before the script. The issue is that $() is async. It may work in Stack Snippet but this is not the answer. Unless you explain why OP code don't work.

Comment: @jcubic i am really agree with you. But task is : "But how to store each textareas at a different index?" and "Doesn't matter if it's with JS or Jquery". I am do that, but you put a minus to me

Answer (score 1):

You must console your array myArray inside function scope after iteration like this:

```
var myArray=[];     
$(function(){
 $("textarea").each(function(){
  myArray.push(this.value);
 });
 console.log(myArray);
});
```

Comment: Sorry I missed it!